# Adding objects that have not defined

Tags: python

```
def addAccount():
    print ("You have chosen to add an account")
    numAcc = 5
    proceed = int(input("Please choose 1 to procedd. If you enter 0, the process will be cancelled.: "))
    while (proceed != 0):
        addName = str(input("Please enter the name of the new account: "))
        addBirthday = str(input("Please enter the birthday of the user (month day, year) :"))
        addAddress = str(input("Please enter the address of the user: "))
        addHkid = str(input("Please enter the HK IDcard number: "))
        addBalance = 0
        numAcc = numAcc + 1
        c6 = Customer (addName, addBirthday, addAddress, addHkid, addBalance)
        CustomerList.append (c6)
        break
```

I have this code for my python code.

I have defined CustomerList above, and customers called from c1 to c5.

I'd like to add new customers called c6 --- until whatever the number is.

Is there a way for me to change some codes or something to be able to add new customers into my customer list? I was trying to use numAcc so that every while loop I can add 1 for that numAcc value and use that number to add account (as number that is added at the end of each customers).

Customers I've defined are like this:

```
c1 = Customer ("Jack", "Jan, 10th, 1996", "430 Davis Ct., San Francisco", "M8875895", 40000)
c2 = Customer ("Smith", "March 24th, 1997", "3-5 Tai Koo Shing, Hong Kong", "M3133242", 600)
c3 = Customer ("Suzy", "May 5th, 1995", "32 Clearwater Bay Ave. Hong Kong", "M8378644", 100000)
c4 = Customer ("Craig", "May 24th, 1993", "700 Powell Street, San Francisco", "M2314565", 70000)
c5 = Customer ("Vic", "September 21st, 1992", "1210 Freud Street, New York", "M1234569", 3400)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def addAccount():
    print ("You have chosen to add an account")
    proceed = 1
    while proceed != 0:
        proceed = int(input("Please enter any number except 0 to proceed. If you enter 0, the process will be cancelled: "))
        addName = str(input("Please enter the name of the new account: "))
        addBirthday = str(input("Please enter the birthday of the user (month day, year) :"))
        addAddress = str(input("Please enter the address of the user: "))
        addHkid = str(input("Please enter the HK IDcard number: "))
        addBalance = 0
        CustomerList.append(Customer(addName, addBirthday, addAddress, addHkid, addBalance))
```

This will keep adding/modifying `Customer`'s to `CustomerList` until the user enters 0.

Comment: I have checked it and what I can do is changing the information of c1 ~ c5 based on what I enter in proceed. +) Oh is this a program that will add customers when the user enters 6 and further numbers to proceed command?

Comment: Is the desired behavior to only keep adding to `CustomerList`? If you enter the highest number in the prompt, it will append to the list instead of modifying existing ones. Did you want me to remove the function of modifying existing ones entirely?

Comment: yes, what I intended to do was just to have adding function

Comment: Okay, it'll only append `Customer`'s to `CustomerList` now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it